# Save / Load Tensorflow Keras model for Prediction only

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a tensorflow keras model with custom losses. After trianing, I want to store the model using `model.save(path)` and in another python script load the model for prediction only using `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)`.

Without `compile=False`, tensorflow will complain about the missing loss function. Calling `model.prediction` however will result in a `Model object has no attribute 'loss'` error message.  I would like to call `model.predict` without needing to specify the loss again.

Is there a solution to save/load a `tf.keras.Model` without the custom loss to using the model for prediction?

**Code**

Since it was asked, the model trains on multiple outputs / losses and I define the losses with lambdas to capture weightings etc. This looks like this:

```
losses = [lambda y_true, y_pred: util.weighted_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred, tf.square(gain_weight)), 
        lambda y_true, y_pred: util.weighted_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred, tf.square(Rd_weight)), 
        lambda y_true, y_pred: util.pole_zero_loss(y_true, y_pred, r_weight, w_weight),
        lambda y_true, y_pred: util.pole_zero_loss(y_true, y_pred, r_weight, w_weight)]


model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=10E-4),
    loss=losses)
```

Comment: Only for prediction I'd save/load weights. And not the entire model.

Comment: Could you please show your code? I have a model with custom loss, but 
`model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)`
`y_pred = model.predict(X_test)`
works well.

Comment: @Yoskutik I think the issue is that I use lambdas for my loss. I'll add it to the question

Comment: Have you tried call `load_model` with `compile=False`, and after that compile the model with whatever losses you want?

Comment: @Yoskutik Yes, that's basically what I do right now but since I need to define a loss, I might as well redefine the loss I use. It's a workaround for an issue that shouldn't require a loss at all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/#load_model-function) keras has `tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath, custom_objects=None, compile=True)` function. If you have custom loss, you can use:

```py
model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'my_loss': my_loss})
```

Where 'my_loss' is your loss' name, and my_loss is the function.

Comment: I've seen this but it seems that I need to store the loss function here as well. I might as well recompile with the loss (which I currently do to prevent the issue). However, since I only want to predict and don't need a loss, I'm really searching for a method were I don't have to worry about the loss after saving the model.